# Filesystem root keeps filling up without me doing anything

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, root, disk-usage

Hey guys Linux newbie here,

I installed a dual-boot of Windows and Linux a couple weeks ago and everything is working fine so far, but I'm encountering a weird problem with space.

Example from today:
I fire up Ubuntu and a message pops up that I have 500mb left, I go offline, 2 hours later I go into Ubuntu again and now I have only 300mb left without saving or doing anything!

```
df -h
```

says the following:

```
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs               787M  9,7M  777M   2% /run
/dev/sda5            12G   11G  277M  98% /
tmpfs               3,9G  176K  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs               3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1           256M   33M  224M  13% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3           911G   58G  854G   7% /media/nunu/Windows
tmpfs               787M  8,0K  787M   1% /run/user/113
tmpfs               787M  112K  787M   1% /run/user/1000
/home/nunu/.Private   12G   11G  277M  98% /home/nunu
```

and

```
du -hs /home/*/*
```

says the following:

```
4,0K    /home/nunu/db
4,0K    /home/nunu/Desktop
282M    /home/nunu/Documents
4,0K    /home/nunu/Downloads
 20K    /home/nunu/examples.desktop
140K    /home/nunu/IdeaProjects
4,0K    /home/nunu/Music
4,0K    /home/nunu/Pictures
4,0K    /home/nunu/Public
 16K    /home/nunu/Schreibtisch
4,0K    /home/nunu/Templates
4,0K    /home/nunu/Videos
```

Does anyone know whats up or how I can find out whats up?

Comment: I did as you said and posted the results, there doesnt seem to be anything especially weird.

Comment: You only looked in your home directory.  Check the whole filesystem:  `cd / && sudo du -hs * 2> /dev/null`    The most common culprit is `/var/log`, but out-of-control output *could* be anywhere.